# Want LED to stay on once it is triggered

Tags: led

Have built the Seattle Univ cell phone detector to locate hidden harassment devices around my home, especially the auto tracker presently installed somewhere in my car.

Circuit works well, and LED comes on when it receives a cell signal (don't use the buzzer).  However, I can't drive and keep an eye on the circuit LED at the same time - especially when investigating the trunk, engine area, and under body as possible hiding places.

So, I'd like to insert a flip flop, SCR, etc., in line with the LED so when the circuit receives a cell signal and the LED lights up, it will stay lit until I get a chance to look at it, then I'll pull the power and turn it off.

All help welcome as to what and where to insert!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fL0Hfx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXJJauAWrzc

https://seattleu.edu/scieng/ece/LM358_RF_Cell_Phone_Detector.html

Answer (score 3):

If you feed the output of the comparator back to its input, that will essentially become your "latch" and you won't need a separate FF.  Once the comparator output goes high, it stays on.  Something like this:

[image]

The two diodes serve as an OR.  Because of the diode following the output of the op-amp, the voltage will be 0.7v lower, but you can compensate for that either using a different pot, or you can increase the gain of the op-amp slightly.

The diodes can be any general purpose such as ubiquitous 1N4148.

Comment: Nice find. Wouldn't V+/U1-B need a slight pull down to define the initial level as it would be floating? Probably a small cap in parallel to ensure the circuit will start up correctly?

Comment: @jippie both good ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly, it seems as if the output of the second op-amp (U1-B) drives low when a signal is detected, allowing current to flow through the LED which turns it on. The first idea that comes to mind that makes the LED stay on is using a [NAND SR latch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_%28electronics%29#SR_NAND_latch) what would latch the LED high when the output signal falls low.

This specific latch has S and R on active low, which fits this circuit because the LED turns on when the output of the op-amp falls low. You could attach a button (with pull-**up** resistor) to Reset, and the output of the op-amp to Set. When Set falls low (the circuit detects a phone signal), Qbar will fall low as well, turning the LED on. Then, when you hit the button, it resets the LED and it turns off again.

You can use the [SN74HC00](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc00.pdf) for your NAND gates.